# how do you create or assign a value to a HTML 'li' element using Node.js?

Tags: html, node.js

I was creating a login form in Node.js using MongoDB when I ran into an issue regarding how to create or assign a value to a `li` element that i want to display on the client side using  HTML. i want to do this because i want to display the username of the user when they have logged in, but the value that i want to display is on another HTML form and that form is called `login.ejs` while the form i want to display this value on is called `main.ejs`. but then i figured that the value of the input box of which is on the `login.ejs` form has to go through the Node.js server file so that the value can be reviewed with the stored value on the MongoDB database. and it just so happens that the `main.ejs` file has to also go through the Node.js server since in the `app.post` function for the `/login` file also contains the `res.render("main");` code.

here is the login function:

```js
app.post("/login", async function(req, res){
  try {
    // check if the user exists
    user = await User.findOne({ username: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${req.body.username}`, 'i') } });
    if (user) {
      // check if password matches
      result = req.body.password === user.password;
      if (result) {
        res.render("main");
        
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "Password doesn't match" });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "User doesn't exist" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error");
    res.status(400).json({ error });
  }
});
```

as you can see there is code for the `res.render("main");` but i want it so that the value of the `user` variable will be displayed in a `li` element on the `main.ejs` file before the `res.render("main");` code. is it possible?